# Some created files aren't Uploading to TFS(VS 2013)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, checkin

I am working with TFS Online and Visual Studio 2013.

When I add a new file to a project and check in both(project and file) the added file isn't uploading to the TFS so when a member get the latest version the projects says that the new file is missed(the poject was checked in correctly).

It happened many times... I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: Can you check if the file's folder or the extensions is defined in any ignore lists? like tfignore, gitignore or else, [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/ms245454(v=vs.110).aspx#tfignore). what is the filename and type of the file?

Comment: The file's type are cs, xml and png. I happened with Forms, Class,XML and an image in Resource.

I don't think it's an issue with folders because for example I checked in 3 pngs and got issue with the last one

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC?